# Azure Table Storage : Saving and retrieving complex structure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to store a complex object in the Azure table storage.

I have implemented `ITableEntity` interface for my entity.

And I have done the implementation for the `ReadEntity` and `WriteEntity` methods as well.

You can see the sample implementation below.

I see the object get saved as a flattened object in the store.
[image]

However, when I try to retrieve the object, It returns me an object only with the `PartitionKey`, 'RowKey', and `Timestamp` values.

[image]

I would like to know what I'm missing in my below implementation or if it's correct, then is it a bug in the library?

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount;

CloudStorageAccount.TryParse("your-connection-string-to-storage-account", out _storageAccount);

var id = "2";

var vehicle = new VehicleDetails { PartitionKey = "Vehicle", RowKey = id, TitleId = id, 
Registration = new Registration { No = "234", Status = "Registered" } };


// add
var  client = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference(typeof(VehicleDetails).Name);
await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Insert(vehicle));

// fetch
var x = await table.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Retrieve<VehicleDetails>("Vehicle", vehicle.TitleId));
var d = (VehicleDetails)x.Result;

Console.WriteLine(d.Registration.No);


public class VehicleDetails : ITableEntity
{
   public string TitleId { get; set; } = default!;

   public Registration Registration { get; set; } = default!;
   public string PartitionKey { get; set; } = default!;
   public string RowKey { get; set; } = default!;
   public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; } = default!;
   public string ETag { get; set; } = default!;

   public void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext)
   {
     TableEntity.ConvertBack<VehicleDetails>(properties, operationContext);
   }

   public IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> WriteEntity(OperationContext operationContext)
   {
    return TableEntity.Flatten(this, operationContext);
   }
 }

 public class Registration
 {
   public string No { get; set; } = default!;
   public string Status { get; set; } = default!;

 }
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
 var tableService = new TableServiceClient("your-connection-string-to-storage-account");
var tableClient = tableService.GetTableClient(typeof(VehicleDetails).Name);
var id = "4";
var vehicle = new VehicleDetails { PartitionKey = "Vehicle", RowKey = id, TitleId = id, Registration = new Registration { No = "234", Status = "Registered" } };

 // add
 var result = await tableClient.AddEntityAsync<VehicleDetails>(vehicle);

 // fetch
 var d = await tableClient.GetEntityAsync<VehicleDetails>(vehicle.PartitionKey, vehicle.RowKey);

  Console.WriteLine(d.Value.Registration.No);

 public class VehicleDetails : ITableEntity
 {

    public string TitleId { get; set; } = default!;

    public Registration Registration { get; set; } = default!;
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; } = default!;
    public string RowKey { get; set; } = default!;
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; } = default!;
    public ETag ETag { get; set; } = default!;
  }

 public class Registration
{
   public string No { get; set; } = default!;
   public string Status { get; set; } = default!;

 }
```

Error/Exception thrown when adding the entity
[image]

Comment: This seems to be some old version of the SDK. Is this existing code or new? If new, I would suggest you use the new SDK as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/44722/is-azure-table-storage-deprecated-as-of-now. If you are still having problems with the new code, then update the question with the code using the latest SDK and we can check.

Comment: Thanks @AnupamChand
I tried with the new `Azure.Data.Tables`  lib. But I get an exception as follows.
`System.NotSupportedException: 'Not supported type Registration`
Below is the changed code snippet.

---------------------
var vehicle = new VehicleDetails { PartitionKey = "Vehicle", RowKey = id, TitleId = id, Registration = new Registration { No = "234", Status = "Registered" } };
var response = await tableClient.AddEntityAsync<VehicleDetails>(vehicle);
---------------------
it seems it doesn't like the complex types as props.  Appreciate any advice.

Comment: @AnupamChand, I've updated the original question with the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

I would store Registration as string inside Table Service:

```
public class VehicleDetails : ITableEntity
{
    public string TitleId { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Registration { get; set; } = default!;
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; } = default!;
    public string RowKey { get; set; } = default!;
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; } = default!;
    public ETag ETag { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

then:

```
    string registrationJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(registration);

    var vehicle = new VehicleDetails
    {
        PartitionKey = "Vehicle",
        RowKey = id,
        TitleId = id,
        Registration = registrationJson
    };
```

to retrieve, just to the opposite:

```
var retrievedVehicle = await tableClient.GetEntityAsync<VehicleDetails>(vehicle.PartitionKey, vehicle.RowKey);

Registration storedRegistration = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Registration>(retrievedVehicle.Value.Registration);
```

Comment: Thank you @Thiago for the answer. This solution may be applicable if you do have one or two nested props. But in my case, I do have quite a bit of nested properties hence I'm not sure whether the solution you provided is viable.

Comment: you need to serialize to JSON the top level.